# URL is not opening in chrome in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my code and requirement is that, need to open URL in same local chrome path. Is it possible??

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe");
        WebDriver d= new ChromeDriver(); ;
        String baseurl = "http://www.facebook.com/";
        d.get(baseurl);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver83\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     String baseurl = "http://www.facebook.com/";
     driver.get(baseurl);
```

Comment: driver should be not d

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads    please download chrome driver and paste into that path then rerun it

Comment: driver is fine, but issue with path only. Not opening URL with this chrome path (C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe) which is installed locally.

Comment: not C://Program Files (x86)//Google//Chrome//Application//chrome.exe");
use following path 
      C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver83\\chromedriver.exe");

Comment: i hope you are using windows machine

Comment: Justin,yes i understood, if i download chrome driver and given the downloaded path then the URL will works fine and i already tried and working good .  But here my requirement is that, i want to open URL in already installed chrome browser which i mentioned.

Comment: You answer and my requirement is different justin.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of chromedriver.exe carefully from your machine.

For Windows users:
**System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");**

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

For MAC users:

**System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","//Users//apple//Downloads//chromedriver");**

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```